# SpecFlow If Step not Binded Build Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, specflow

I am using SpecFlow for Testing My Web Applications and my code repository has become too huge,

I have a team of person working on the same code, though this has just happened only once that someone changed someone else's step names, but I want to integrate a build check in visual studio verifying that all steps in the feature files are atleast binded to a step in class file.

Is it possible to do that in visual studio Post Build events of somewhere else?

Comment: If step is not binded then integration test should fail automatically. Does it not suffice?

Comment: yes, but i want to stop it at build time, so we don't get to know it at CI level or something after check-ins, as developers usually run their own cases only

Answer (score 0):

The only way for checking is at the moment without running all the tests is to use the Step Definition Report (http://specflow.org/documentation/Reporting/).

But this doesn't break the build.